# Bash script that copies names of all files with a specific first part of name

Tags: bash, file, csv

I've got a folder with about 4000 picutres, of about 800 different different object.

Basically all pictures of a specific objects start with AR (5 digit code here)
and finish with _1.jpg , _2.png depending on how many picutres there are

I'm basically trying to note all of them down in a file with the following format
AR05477;/AR05477_1.png|/AR05477_2.png|/AR05477_3.jpg
AR05478:/AR05478_1.jpg etc

I tried using grep / ls (since they are all in the same folder) with different flags and options that i've found in google and using > to export the output, and i've got close to it by using printf, but I did not manage to get them exactly in this form, Can anybody help me please?

Many thanks!

Comment: Do you just want a glob?  For example does `ls AR*_[12].png` give you the list you want?  Also, show us you actual attempts and perhaps we can help with those, but without knowing exactly what you've tried it's tough to help

Comment: Eric, It's not exactly a glob that i'm looking for, I basically need all the full names of files starting with AR05477 in a line, like AR05477, AR05477_1 etc and a different line for each next one, I've tried using commands like printf "%s\n" *snp* | wc -1
but could not manage to get the format I'm looking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`find` is a good tool for this. Try

```
find . -regextype posix-extended -iregex '.*/AR[0-9]{5}_[0-9]+\.jpg'
```

Now chain that with some awk to get what you're looking for:

```
find . -regextype posix-extended -iregex './AR[0-9]{5}_[0-9]+\.jpg' \
| sed 's/\.\///' \
| awk -F"_"  '{ print $1,$0 }' \
| awk '{arr[$1]=(arr[$1]?arr[$1]";"$2:$1";"$2)} END { for (i in arr) print arr[i]}'
```

Comment: find: Unknown predicate -E  :-(

Comment: It looks close, but I only get the ones ending with _1

Comment: Ok so I've changed it to find -regextype posix-extended -iregex '.*/AR[0-9]{5}_[0-9].jpg'
 And i have to correct order, is there any chance to have the starting AR(code) printed before having the file names with _1 _2 etc out?

Comment: @C.Edelweiss one more update. not the prettiest, but I think it'll work?